# Is recording audio supported in Firefox OS Simulator?

Tags: audio, firefox-os

I just wanted to know if accessing microphone api's are permitted in FirefoxOS Simulator.
I want to utilize mediaRecorder api(or audio-capture) in my application.  But to implement and test it do I need a real device?

I don't have one, so is it possible to emulate this in Simulator?
I tried to get the "recorder" app work in the simulator to test if that app can access the laptop's microphone device, but It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the example you tried?
https://github.com/mdn/web-dictaphone/
here is documentation for the example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API/Using_the_MediaRecorder_API

I tried this on 1.3.0.0-prerelease on the Flame and it worked but it did not work on the simulator.  I believe the docs say 2.0 but it worked on the 1.3 version for my flame.

Comment: I tried that one too along with recorder. If I can test it in simulator then I will borrow dictaphone's approach to impliment the speech input in my app. But I need to be able to test it. I'll try it once in simulator 1.3 and 1.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal getUserMedia calls to access the microphone input in Firefox Desktop and test it in there. You might want to change your code around a bit so it will also work in the desktop browser, but that's the quickest way.